# How can i dynamically use images in Crossfading image? (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the App.js Page:

Imports which i used:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import CrossfadeImage from "react-crossfade-image";
```

Function:

```
  export default function App() {
   const [curImg, setCurImg] = useState(0);
```

Here i const two images in an array:

```
   const images = [
        "http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/c1/2f/4c/c12f4cba-1d9a-f6bf-2240-04085d3470ec/icon175x175.jpeg",
        "http://is2.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple122/v4/d2/36/28/d23628e5-c9bf-d0fb-104f-61fa52976ff5/source/175x175bb.jpg",
      ];
```

UseEffect Hook which is handle the crossfading:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        let interval = null;
    
        interval = setInterval(() => {
          if (curImg < 1) {
            setCurImg(img => img + 1);
          } else {
            setCurImg(0);
          }
        }, 3000);
    
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
      }, [curImg]);
```

Returned CrossfadeImage which is using that two images:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <CrossfadeImage
        src={images[curImg]}
        duration={1000}
        delay={200}
        timingFunction={"ease-out"}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You don't need UseEffect Hook to handle crossfading if you are using the library.
[See this example](https://github.com/khanglu/react-crossfade-image/blob/master/example/App.js)

Comment: This is working fine but i set images static. I want it to be dynamic so it can be randomly crossfading

Answer (score 0):

change `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
   const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (curImg < 1) {
           setCurImg(img => img + 1);
         } else {
           setCurImg(0);
         }
   }, 1000);
   return () => clearInterval(interval);
 }, []);
```

Comment: That's not my intention i want to images randomly fading to each other like a loop.

Comment: use rand number or loop